# Story that includes a description: "Two concentric circles, intersecting at three points"

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to find a story I read as a child.  I remember little about it except for the following:

- I suspect I read it before 1985, but it was a school library book which means it could be God knows how much older than that.
- This may mean it was a book meant for younger readers.
- In memory it "feels" longer than a short story, but I was a bit young to be reading novels.  If I had to guess, I would guess novella length or shorter.
- English language, available in the United States.
- Contains several descriptions and ideas that stuck with me:

  - The overall idea was that there were "parallel" worlds, parallel like the pages of a book, except for one that was (for whatever reason) skew to the rest, or warped somehow, and therefore intersecting the rest
  - Geometry between that world and the rest seemed fundamentally incompatible as a result
  - The most evocative example of this (by definition, since it is the only one I recall with clarity) is a description of... something... as looking like "Two concentric circles, intersecting in three places."  This is obviously gibberish (concentric circles intersect nowhere unless they also have the same radius in which case they overlap perfectly; non-concentric circles that do intersect do so only at two points) but I was just old enough to realize it was gibberish being used to a purpose.  It stuck with me.

Comment: That last part reminds me of a specific branch of mathematic where everything is possible, like: usually, for a given point and a line, there's one line passing by this point which can be parallel to the first line. But in this branch, for a given point and a line, there's no way a line can possibly pass on that dot and be parallel to the first line. Though I can't remember how that "branch" was called...

Comment: Technically speaking, in 3 dimensions you could have two concentric circles of equal radius, at 90 degrees to one another, which cross at two points.

Comment: @Clockwork Non-Euclidean Geometry

Comment: Just for fun, I've just modeled two concentric circles which appear to intersect at 3 points. The trick is that a) one circle is only fractionally smaller than the other, b) one is orthogonal to the other (a different 3d plane), and c) I'm viewing the model in a very carefully selected perspective.

Comment: Two concentric circles, intersecting at three points: this is possible if the two circles are _identical_ in dimension, position, and, assuming 3D space, orientation. Of course, they actually intersect at ∞ points. If you're looking for circles that intersect at _exactly_ three points, that's a different story....

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman: they don't even have to be 90 degrees to each other; they just need to be concentric and of identical radius, lying on non-identical planes. But as you said, that'll get you exactly two points of intersection, not three.

Comment: In fact, it's of course impossible for *any* 2 closed shaped to intersect at an odd number of points, assuming you don't count tangents as intersections.  But that's kind of the whole point - the 2 circles in 3 points is an impossibility that is part of a hallucinatory experience, and could not exist in real geometry.

Comment: To add to the mathematical discussion, you could have an oval that is tangent to one point of the circle and crossing the circle at the opposite side for 3 intersections, but that goes against "concentric" and "2 circles".

Comment: @Clockwork As popctrl said, you're probably thinking of Non-Euclidean Geometry, but that is *not* a branch of geometry where "everything is possible". Euclidean geometry states that if you have distinct lines A, B, and C such that neither A nor B intersect C, then A and B never intersect each other. (i.e. If A is parallel to C and B is parallel to C, then A is parallel to B). Non-Euclidean Geometries (e.g. elliptic or hyperbolic geometry) are any geometries that do not have that requirement. The rest of Euclid's axioms still apply. (On large scales, the *universe* may be non-Euclidean.)

Comment: There's now a [question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3328227/is-there-a-known-non-euclidean-geometry-where-two-concentric-circles-of-differen) about the specific geometry of this story.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[The Universe Between](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1417219.The_Universe_Between) by Alan E. Nourse.

> Bob Benedict is one of the few scientists able to make contact with the invisible, dangerous world of The Thresholders and return—sane! For years he has tried to transport—and receive—matter by transmitting it through the mysterious, parallel Threshold. At first his efforts met only with failure and madness. But now The Thresholders have risen in fury. Somehow Bob Benedict must make one more trip into that land of peril and pacify them before they succeed in hurling his planet—piece by piece into the oblivion of infinity.

It was first published in 1951 (the edition I've linked above is from 1965) so it matches your time frame, and it's only 220 pages long (in hardback form) so it's only a short novel.

The paragraph you remember is:

> Incredibly, something changed. A pause, a sag, as though some terrible pressure had
>   suddenly been released. Their fear was still there, biting into him, but there was something else. He was aware of his body around him in its curious configuration of orderly disorder, its fragments whirling about him like sections of a crazy quilt. **Two concentric circles of different radii intersecting each other at three different points**. Twisting cubic masses interlacing themselves into the jumbled incredibility of a geometric nightmare. The blackness was around him, the cold of the place dug into him and the fear hung around him like a cloak. He had the hallucinatory sense of being torn apart, roughly, in a jagged line from top to bottom and of seeing, unclearly, the parts of his body in mutilated distortion. Did he appear to them as some grotesque geometric distortion, a crooked, twisted, impossible mass of lines and shadows and forms? He must; they couldn't possibly see him as he saw himself in his own place. Yet something had happened, now he could sense that the Thresholders were all around him, with a pervading sense of excitement.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely it.  I remembered the description of a human body decomposed into fragments, too, but not well enough to include it.  That is the clincher.  Thanks!